# How do I count the number of words if the user enters multiple lines/spaces?

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I have a char array, which contains what the user has inputted. How would I count the words?
The user in permitted to to do something crazy like:

```
hello this
               is a test
   how are
you today?
```

So the number of words here should be 9 but my program tells me 23. Why is this not working? Its counting the spaces, but I have taken that into account with `sentence_entered[i + 1] != ' '`

My code:

```
int i = 0;    
while (sentence_entered[i] != '\0') {

        if (
            (sentence_entered[i] == ' ' ||
            sentence_entered[i] == '\n') &&
            (sentence_entered[i + 1] != ' ' ||
            sentence_entered[i + 1] != '\n')
           ) {
            words += 1;
    }
i++
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The negation of `a || b` is `!a && !b`.

Your condition should read:

```
       (sentence_entered[i] == ' ' ||
        sentence_entered[i] == '\n') &&
        (sentence_entered[i + 1] != ' ' &&
        sentence_entered[i + 1] != '\n')
```

Comment: This fixed it, but can you explain to me why `(sentence_entered[i + 1] != ' ' &&
        sentence_entered[i + 1] != '\n')` has && instead of ||? Because a single space in the array can't be both a space and a line break at the same time? Thats why I did or?

My logic:
The array [i] is a space or an line break. Also check if the [i + 1] is a space OR a line break. i + 1 cannot be both a space and a line break?

Comment: The first part  (sentence_entered[i] == ' ' ||
        sentence_entered[i] == '\n')  is checking for white space.  The second part is checking for not white space (sentence_entered[i + 1] != ' ' &&
        sentence_entered[i + 1] != '\n')

Comment: @Zoey You've got it, I think. For the current character not to be part of a word, it must be a space **or** it must be a newline. For the next character to be part of a word, it must not be a space **and** it must not be a newline.

Comment: Consider using the 'isspace' function instead.  This code will not work for all whitespace characters.

Comment: @iamJP I only explained what I thought the OP needed to know. I don't think that telling them about `isspace` would unpuzzle them given the question, but if you think it would, you should post it as a comment on the question.

Comment: Thanks guys, I get it now

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov please do not assume that users of the site are “guys”